# Clustering of sequential data

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

Given the following scenario, I have a really long street. Each house on the street has some number of children. If I were to sequentially append the number of children in each house along an array, I could get some array like:

```
x = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
```

I want to locationally determine areas where the households cluster, i.e. I want to group the 2's together, the 3's together, and the 2's at the end together. Normally on 1D data I would sort, determine difference, and find clusters of 1, 2, and 3. But here, I want to keep the index of these values as a factor. So I wanto to end up identifying clusters as:

```
index: value
0-4 :  1
5-8:   2
9-12:  1
13-16: 3
17-20: 1
21-24: 2
```

I have seen mean shift used for this detection, and would like to implement this in python. I have also seen kernal density functions. Does anyone know how best to implement this in python?

Edit: To make something clear, I have simplified the problem. At each cluster of integers, the actual problem I would try to address has a gaussian distribtuion of values around that integer value. So I would have a list more like:

```
x = [0.8, 0.95, 1.2, 1.3, 2.2, 1.6, 1.9, 2.1, 1.1, .7, .9, .9, 3.4, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 1.2, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 12.0]
```

Comment: Add `python` tag to your question.

Comment: Cross-post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145248/clustering-of-sequential-data/145263

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach:

```
x = [0.8, 0.95, 1.2, 1.3, 2.2, 1.6, 1.9, 2.1, 1.1, .7, .9, .9, 3.4, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 1.2, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 12.0]
cluster = []
for i, v in enumerate(x):
    v = round(v)
    if not cluster or cluster[-1][2] != v:
        cluster.append([i, i, v])
    else:
        cluster[-1][1] = i
```

This results in a list of `[start, end, value]` lists:

```
[[ 0,  3, 1],
 [ 4,  7, 2],
 [ 8, 11, 1],
 [12, 14, 3],
 [15, 15, 2],
 [16, 19, 1],
 [20, 23, 2]]
```

Your desired output wasn't zero-based, therefore the indices look a bit different

---

**Edit**:

updated algorithm for updated version of problem